# Adding new column to clustered column store indexed table

Tags: sql-server-2017, alter-table, clustered-index, columnstore

I designing clustered column store indexed fact tables.

Later on many new columns might be added to these currently ~90 columns tables.

How adding new nullable column is affected by the size (number of rows) of the table?
Is it a metadata only operation, or some data reorganization goes on under the hood which i need to take into account?

Comment: Roughly how many rows are in the table?

Comment: @J.D. 300-400 million rows.